# BigQuery WITH clause throws "Unrecognized name" error

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to use the WITH operator to get a count from a view I generated (`foo.bar.cohort`), which can then be used to calculate a value from data in my main view (`foo.bar.retention_30d`). Seems like this should be pretty straightforward, but I am getting this error when I attempt to execute the query below:

> Unrecognized name: total_users at [12:29]

Here's the query:

```
  #standardsql
WITH
  total_users AS (
  SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT uid) as sum_users
  FROM
    `foo.bar.cohort`
  WHERE
    first_seen_date > '2016-12-31'
    AND first_seen_date < '2017-02-01')
SELECT
  ROUND(SUM(retained_users)/total_users.sum_users, 2) AS avg,
  SUM(retained_users) AS retained,
  SUM(active_users) AS active,
  total_users.sum_users
FROM
  `foo.bar.retention_30d`
WHERE
  period = 27
  AND (created_at > '2016-12-31'
    AND created_at < '2017-02-01')
```

Schema for `foo.bar.cohort`:

[image]

Schema for `foo.bar.retention_30d`:

[image]

Pointers/hints are most welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`total_users` is a table, not a column. If you want to refer to the column inside it, you need to use that name instead. For example:

```
#standardsql
WITH
  total_users AS (
  SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT uid) as sum_users
  FROM
    `foo.bar.cohort`
  WHERE
    first_seen_date > '2016-12-31'
    AND first_seen_date < '2017-02-01')
SELECT
  ROUND(SUM(retained_users)/(SELECT sum_users FROM total_users), 2) AS avg,
  SUM(retained_users) AS retained,
  SUM(active_users) AS active,
  (SELECT sum_users FROM total_users) AS sum_users
FROM
  `foo.bar.retention_30d`
WHERE
  period = 27
  AND (created_at > '2016-12-31'
    AND created_at < '2017-02-01')
```

Comment: Ah ha! I was trying to reference sum_users from within total_users, not realizing I still had to operate on it like a table. Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 0):

what about this one?

```sql
SELECT a
FROM table_with_parameters AS t
JOIN my_table_fuction(t.par1, t.par2, t.par3) AS u
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.